# Square integrable borel probability measures on Euclidean spaces are the law of random variables from an atomless polish space

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory

Could someone provide me with a reference or proof for the following: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be an atomless probability space, with $\Omega$ a Polish space. Given $f$ a random vector on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ denote by $L(f)$ its law, i.e. the induced measure on the Euclidean target space. Then, for any $k$, and any square integrable measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, there exists a random vector $f$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ with $L(f)=\mu$.

In Cardaliaguet's Notes on Mean Field Games, subsection 6.1 pg 43, he mentions the result as 'recall'. Meanwhile Keisler, Sun on Why saturated probability spaces are necessary, Lemma 2.1(ii), they mention something stronger as a well-known result.

Answer (score 1):

The proof I like to remember goes as follows.

Since all uncountable Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic, it suffices to prove this for $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $k=1$, so that $P, \mu$ are both measures on $\mathbb{R}$, with $P$ atomless.  Let $F,G : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be their respective cumulative distribution functions.  Then the pushforward $F_* P$ is Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $[0,1]$ (easy exercise; show that $(F_* P)([0,a]) = a$).  Now let $G^\leftarrow : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $G^\leftarrow(t) = \sup\{ x : G(x) < t\}$ be the "inverse" of $G$.  Show that $G^\leftarrow_* \lambda = \mu$ (also an exercise, or see Theorem 1.2.2 of Durrett, *Probability: Theory and Examples*).  We conclude that $(G^{\leftarrow} \circ F)_* P = \mu$, which is to say that if we consider $G^{\leftarrow} \circ F$ as a random variable on $(\mathbb{R}, P)$, its law is $\mu$.

The square integrability is not needed, and this works equally well if $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{R}^k$ are replaced by any other Polish spaces.